# Setting up a second cart in a sub directory

Tags: content-management-system, bigcommerce

I am working on a site currently running big commerce. I need to move all the cart and all content over to a new template and would like to setup a development environment in a sub directory `/dev` within the `/root` directory already containing a store.

Is it possible to setup a second "development" store in my current store's `/dev` sub directory that wouldn't interfere with the live store? This way I can mirror the live store in the development environment so when I'm finished creating the new look, I can just move the pages over and everything would fit nicely.

Also, if this is possible, how can I access the development store when it's within the sub directory? I created a sub domain that redirects to the `/dev` folder within the `/root` folder but when I try to access it `http://url/dev` or `http://url/dev/index.html` it returns a page not found error.

It would look something like this:

```
\root
    <!-- files and folders for live store -->
    \dev
        <!-- files and folders for development store -->
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to add another store to a subdirectory.

You can add another Bigcommerce store to a subdomain however. You could set up http://yourstore.com (live store) and http://dev.yourstore.com (development store).